# Is possible to mirror a chart in another place?

Tags: excel, charts

I have a chart on one excel worksheet, and I want to show it in another worksheet without moving the original chart.

I do not want to copy and paste it, because if I modify the original chart (for example, changing his format), it will not be reproduced in the copy.

Is possible to hack it to show the chart in another page? Maybe a picture whose image is automatically taken from the original chart?

I frequently modify the original chart, and I have another worksheet where I watch many charts at once.

Comment: It is very possible and there are certaintly a lot of ways do do it. Are you familiar with VBA?

Comment: @ JulianG I'm familiar with VBA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a dynamic image, without VBA.

It will work best if the original chart is perfectly aligned with a range of cells.

- select the range of cells behind the chart, for example A1:D10. You may want to give that range a name with the Name Manager, i.e. `myChart`, for convenience
- on the Home ribbon, click the Copy dropdown and select "Copy as Picture"
- accept the defaults "as shown on screen" and "picture" and hit OK
- in the target worksheet (in the SAME workbook), select a cell and paste from the clipboard
- select the pasted image and click into the formula bar. Enter the cell range you copied it from into the formula bar, e.g. `=Sheet1!$A$1:$D$10`, or, if you have set up a name, use that, like `=myChart`

The image is now dynamic and will reflect whatever content is showing in the specified cell range. If you resize the original cells, the dynamic image will distort.

Be aware that you are not creating an image of the actual chart, but only of the cells that the chart covers. If you move the chart away from the range, then it will not be visible in the dynamic image.

That's why this technique works best if the chart is perfectly aligned with a range of cells.

More details about this technique, using it to create combination Sparklines is in this [article](https://teylyn.com/articles/stacked-column-and-combination-charts-with-excel-2010-sparklines/) written in 2011, but everything still applies.

Comment: I bow to the master!